# How to get your php file working in local with LAMP

Tags: apache2, lamp

I installed LAMP in my ubuntu 20.04 server, and after a bit of hassle I got everything working finally. However I haven't yet figured out how to run my `php/html` file in local. I have always used Xampp for Windows and I don't know how to deal with LAMP now.

In Xampp, it was just a matter to put your project folders in the `htdocs`  folder and then run on your browser something like:

```
my_IP_machine/site1
```

or for another project

```
my_IP_machine/site2
```

That's it.

But if I create a folder (say, `mysite`) in  `/var/www/` and I then run:

```
http://192.168.1.10/mysite/index.html
```

I got:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.10 Port 80
```

I also read this guide here:

https://serverspace.io/support/help/install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20.04

and tried to set  a virtual host, but it didn't work either.
Could you please help me figure it out?
Thanks

Comment: You say *"and tried to set a virtual host, but it didn't work either."*. What have you tried exactly? [edit] the question adding all the information.

Comment: Have you tried with `localhost` in the address bar, or the `127.0.0.1` IP?

Comment: @Levente I have ubuntu on a VM machine with its own IP address

Comment: @jeysmith 127.0.0.1 is the local ip address, it will always work on any machine. If you browse it you'll see the apache configuration server page.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity           I have no GUI in ubuntu. I use it just to run services